Issue when performing mysqldump - Matomo - MySQL error 2013
On premise setup, **Ubuntu 20.04:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor

Memory: 64GB RAM**
mysql  Ver 8.0.40-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))



We’re recently being confronted by an error occurring most of the time when trying to perform a dump of the database.
Dump Command:
sudo mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="$PASS" --compression-algorithms=zlib --quick --single-transaction -u"$USER" -h"$HOST" "$DB_NAME"

Results in:
`mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `matomo_archive_blob_2024_10` at row: 305237`

` mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `matomo_archive_blob_2023_07` at row: 277559`

` mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `matomo_archive_blob_2024_10` at row: 135449`

workaroud was temporarely setting innodb_force_recovery = 1 during the dump and then put back to 0 after the backup is complete, this used to be successful a couple of times but that now also returns errors.
I tried to repair, autorepair, optimize, finetuning:
[mysqld]
#
key_buffer_size         = 16M
thread_stack            = 512K

max_allowed_packet= 2G   
wait_timeout = 28800          
interactive_timeout = 28800    
net_read_timeout = 1200         
net_write_timeout= 1200       
net_buffer_length = 64K

# InnoDB - Tuning and performance improvements
#
innodb_open_files = 5000
innodb_force_recovery = 0
innodb_redo_log_capacity = 21G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 160GB
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 64
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_io_capacity = 1000
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 1G
net_buffer_length = 64K

Anybody has a solution for this? Encounter also the same errors?

This question is similar to: MySQL - MySQLDump problems with large table. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
